# Can't get an output while calling java web service using php

Tags: java, php, web-services

I have create a web service using java. I used the below code to call the web service using php.

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8080/imageCom/wsdl/CompareImage.wsdl");
$stock = "http://localhost/pic/blueTshirts/b10.jpg";
$parameters= array("url"=>$stock);
$values = $client->checkSimilarity($parameters);       
var_dump($values);
```

When I run the code I get the following output. But it doesn't display the result

**output: object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }**

Here is my WSDL

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://simalarity.imageCom" xmlns:intf="http://simalarity.imageCom" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://simalarity.imageCom">
<!--
WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)
-->
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://simalarity.imageCom">
<element name="checkSimilarity">
<complexType>
<sequence>
<element name="url" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
</element>
<element name="checkSimilarityResponse">
<complexType/>
</element>
</schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="checkSimilarityRequest">
<wsdl:part element="impl:checkSimilarity" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="checkSimilarityResponse">
<wsdl:part element="impl:checkSimilarityResponse" name="parameters"></wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="CompareImage">
<wsdl:operation name="checkSimilarity">
<wsdl:input message="impl:checkSimilarityRequest" name="checkSimilarityRequest"></wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output message="impl:checkSimilarityResponse" name="checkSimilarityResponse"></wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="CompareImageSoapBinding" type="impl:CompareImage">
<wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="checkSimilarity">
<wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
<wsdl:input name="checkSimilarityRequest">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output name="checkSimilarityResponse">
<wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="CompareImageService">
<wsdl:port binding="impl:CompareImageSoapBinding" name="CompareImage">
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/imageCom/services/CompareImage"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

What I am doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: No, I created the web service using eclipse.First I create a dyanmic web project and added the java class. Then created the web service for that java class. I tested the web service using sample test client in java. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are getting standard class object array in return.

You have to extract the values accordingly

print_r($array) will print your array recursively.

You may also loop over an array of objects like below,

```
foreach ($array as $key => $object) {
echo $object->object_property;
}
```

Think of an array as a collection of things. It's a bag where you can store your stuff and give them a unique id (key) and access them.

Comment: When I run print_r($array) , I get the output as " stdClass Object ( ) "

Comment: It should return a value. I tested it using java client. It gives me the value.

Comment: it prints the output in glassfish server console. But how to print it in php page?